# Jquery 1.10.2 for new ASP MVC 5 project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have just installed visual studio 2013 and when I create a new Web project asp mvc i get a jquery 1.10.2 library.

This is seriously old. The latest release is 2.0.3.

Is there some technically reason for this? Or will i just have to update-package every time i create a new ASP project.

Comment: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/07/03/jquery-1-10-2-and-2-0-3-released/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually 1.10.2 is one month newer than 2.0.3 - it was released in May 2013.

The reason version 1.x is bundled with MVC projects by default is because it still supports legacy browsers. The 2.x versions of jQuery had lots of legacy supporting code for browsers such as IE6 and 7 removed to save bloat and gain performance.

Therefore if you need to support older browsers use 1.12.4. If not, use the latest version available (currently 3.x at time of writing).

Comment: Seems like a step back to start supporting older browsers in the newer version of MVC =S